# What should be the routes and http methods for phone number verification in REST API?

Tags: javascript, rest, api-design

I am curious about the API endpoint structure and HTTP methods that I need to use to successfully verify a phone number. What is the right format that I need to use as per REST API guidelines? Also what responses should each API return?

I am trying to update a phone number. This is what I have tried:

**API 1 - POST /verification** - Creates verification entity and sends a verification code

Inputs: `phone_number: '+19876543210'`

Response:

```
{id: 'verification_id', status: 'enum[pending, completed]'}
```

**API2 - POST /verification/{verification_id}/verify**

Inputs: `code: '123456'`

Response:

```
{id: 'verification_id', status: 'enum[pending, completed]'}
```

**API3 - PATCH /account/:id/profile** - Replaces current phone number

Inputs: `{id: 'current_phone_id', number: 'new_number', verification_id: 'verification_id'}`

Response:

```
Updated Profile object
```

Comment: I like the first approach personally. Maybe `/verification` is a bit too ambiguous though, maybe something like `/phone-numbers/verifications`?

Answer (score 0):

Well this is heavily opinion based. But here is what I probably would do based on your proposal.

**1. - POST /accounts/{account}/phones** Add new phone number (unverified, send sms)

You should name your resource endpoints plural which is usually best rest practices.
And as @sp00n already pointed out, `verification` is  bit too general, you may include phone here.

Also this endpoint should response with a `HTTP 202 Accepted` since the resource is only partially ready (awaiting sms). Or at least use `201 Created` since a new resource has been created.

**2. - PATCH /accounts/{account}/phones/{phone}** Verify phone number

Using `POST /verification/{verification_id}/verify` sounds more like an rpc call. In restful apis you usually change the state of a resource by modifying it.

**3. - PATCH /accounts/{account}** - Replace primary phone number

Inputs: `{id: 'user_id', primary_phone: 'phone_number'}`.

This way phone is a sub resource of an account and there is no need to remove it after changing the primary phone number.